# Removing value from UITableView causes crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a UITableView and when I click on a cell I update a value in firebase to be true. I also implemented the ability to delete the UITableViewCell. The problem is that if the cell has been clicked on (updated) and then deleted the app crashes. When I have a look in firebase the value that has been updated has not been deleted (everything else has been), this only happens if the cell has been updated. This is what I got

```
// remove task

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let taskToDelete = groupTask[indexPath.row]

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        groupTask.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        DataService.instance.REF_GROUPS.child(group!.key).child("task").child(taskToDelete.id).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, refer) in
            if error != nil {

            } else {

            }
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

// update task value

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? GroupTaskCell else { return }

    if cell.isSelected == true {
        let selected = groupTask[indexPath.row]
        DataService.instance.REF_GROUPS.observe(.value) { (snapShot) in
            DataService.instance.updateTaskStatus(desiredGroup: self.group!, selected: true, atIndexpath: indexPath.row, childPath: selected.id, handler: { (complete) in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    } else {

    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


// update task status

func updateTaskStatus(desiredGroup: Group, selected: Bool, atIndexpath: Int, childPath: String, handler: @escaping (_ taskArray: [Task]) -> ()) {

    REF_GROUPS.child(desiredGroup.key).child("task").child(childPath).updateChildValues(["selected": selected])
    }
```

EDIT!

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1b5915f18) to 'NSString' (0x1b5921ad8).
>   2018-01-01 17:38:53.431901+0200 WireUp[587:103199] Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1b5915f18) to 'NSString' (0x1b5921ad8).
>   (lldb)

What firebase looks like before I delete the task:
[image: What firebase looks like before I delete the task]

And after: [image: And after]

As you can see it is not removing the value that has been updated and that is what's causing the crash. I appreciate all help.

```
func addTask(withTask task: String, andPeople people: String, forUID uid: String, withGroupKey groupKey: String?, selectedStatus selected: Bool, sendComplete: @escaping (_ taskCreated: Bool ) -> ()) {
    if groupKey != nil {
        REF_GROUPS.child(groupKey!).child("task").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["taskToDo": task, "peopleToDoTask": people, "senderId": uid, "selected": selected])
        sendComplete(true)
    } else {

    }
}

func updateTaskStatus(desiredGroup: Group, selected: Bool, childPath: String, handler: @escaping (_ taskArray: [Task]) -> ()) {

    REF_GROUPS.child(desiredGroup.key).child("task").child(childPath).updateChildValues(["selected": selected])
    }


func configureTaskCell(taskToDo task: String, nameForPerson name: String, isSelected: Bool ) {
    self.task.text = task
    self.name.text = name
    if isSelected {
        self.chechImg.isHidden = false
    } else {
        self.chechImg.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the crash result . . ?

Comment: I put the crash result above

Comment: I think you have a problem with cellForRowAtIndexPath: data source method where you are assigning a null value to restricted string . . . I suggest you to add break point on all exception which will point to the exact line that where is problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the code you've provided isn't the issue. It's being deleted correctly but as you delete it, it's also updating again with just the **selected: true**. Somewhere in your code, it'll be trying to fetch the rest of the data, including the **selected: true** BUT it's not there; resulting in the crash. You may want to do some debugging to see where you're actually updating this selected value to your database and get rid of it

Comment: The problem is that it is not removing the value from firebase and that then causes the crash

Comment: Yes I know why I get the crash (it can't find the data), but don't know why the selected: true is updated again. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @Oscar I'd personally head over to Xcode's search bar (on the left - hit cmd + 3) and search for "selected" or "selected": true. This will literally show everywhere that you're calling it to help you find where it could be being called once deleted. I'd also put a break point on each one of those lines to know exactly if it's being called or not, as it will hit that break point when you delete something.

Comment: I have gone through the code and can't find the problem. Are you able to look through it if you can find whats wrong? It would be much appreciated. I put the code above @daniel

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `self.tableView.reloadData()` from within the table view delegate functions try updating and deleting cells using the `beginUpdate()` and `endUpdate()` methods of UITableView. You won't crash and you won't be reloading the whole table. In Obj-C, it looks like this for removing and updating a cell:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];

[tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: This deletes everything correctly, but for some reason, it creates a new child in firebase and there passes in "selected": true and the app crashes. Seems like there is a problem with something else

Comment: First of all `begin- / endUpdates` is pointless – and even has no effect at all before and after `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` – and secondly `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is redundant because `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` updated the UI already.